# how to get the value of ng-repeat input angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i created some dynamic input from ng-repeat.

i just want to know, how to get the **input** value of each dynamically generated input field in html..
https://jsfiddle.net/a6at8js6/5/

**html**

```
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="author in author_group" class="authorAndTagGroup">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in author">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{key}}</label> 
        <input type="text" value="{{value}}">
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**angularjs**

```
var app = angular.module("mainApp",  []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){

$scope.authors = [{'author_name': 'akshay', 'about_author':'this is about author', 'author_image':'image url here'}];

 $scope.author_group = [];

    for (var key in $scope.authors) {
     $scope.author_group.push({'Author Name' : $scope.authors[key].author_name, 'About the Author' : $scope.authors[key].about_author, 'Author Image' : $scope.authors[key].author_image, 'Author Linkedin Profile' : '', 'Author Twitter Profile' : ''});
   }
   console.log($scope.author_group);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind your input text to the author object's key'd property works.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="author[key]">
```

Note the following as suggested by ebinmanuval does *NOT* work; this is because it fails to mutate the underlying author object and instead just overwrites the value property. The trick here is that we want to bind the model to a *reference type* like an object not a *value type* like a string, that way when we mutate the model the underlying type is mutated as well:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/775dfa9y/4/

Comment: @AkshayKumar, why you are, reject my answer

Comment: @Jimbrooism i dint reject somebody else did... i dont know

Comment: @AkshayKumar ok, you can avoid the for loop if you go with my solution